# Differentiating between 32-QAM and 32-PSK

Tags: modulation, qpsk

A communication channel with 4 kHz bandwidth requires 40 kbps data rate.
What is the most suitable modulation technique to use in this particular scenario?

for this I used the Nyquist theorem.
 C=2B log2 L

40*1000=2*4*1000*log2 L

L=2^5 = 32

Now my problem is what the correct modulation technique is. I searched over google and found that apart from 32QAM, 32PSK exists.

I'm new to this stuff so an input is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, start by drawing the constellation diagram for both modulations, preferably on squared paper (be *precise*). Do you notice any difference between the two modulations? Assume the data is uniformly distributed, what can you say of SNR as a function of transmitted power?

Comment: You may want to familiarize yourself with the basic differences between MQAM and MPSK (M-ary, M is some arbitrary number). Outside of BER vs. Es/No, recall that you're also trading complexity at the transmitter and receiver ends when it comes to modulation / demodulation. Additionally, in MPSK, all symbols will have the same energy whereas in MQAM, symbol energy will differ based on its position in the constellation. Check this out for 16QAM vs 16PSK: http://www.dsplog.com/2008/03/29/comparing-16psk-vs-16qam-for-symbol-error-rate/

Comment: The thesis of Stewart Thomas under Dr. Reynolds has IQ plots and how to derive constellations.  32-QAM would take a lot of capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

If we exclude circuit complexity (QAM would be more complex), in terms of a less required eb/No at the receiver, a 32QAM will always be better than a 32PSK. Take into account that in a QAM modulation, samples will have a bigger separation in the constellation, which means that more noise is required to produce a sample error.
Other option could be a 32APSK